# How to ActionResult Edit in MVC using Entity Framework with two tables (one to one)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I just want to ask a question, I'm a beginner in ASP.Net MVC.

This is my case:

I have two tables..

Student Table : ID (Primary Key), Name, and Class
Bag Table : ID (Primary Key), Brand

ID (Student) relationship with ID (Bag)
One to One Relationship..

this is my controller code

```
// POST: Students/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Nama,Kelas,Brand")] Student Student, Bag Bag)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Students.Add(Student);
            Bag.Id = Student.Id;
            db.Bag.Add(Bag);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.Id = new SelectList(db.Bag, "Id", "Brand", Student.Id);
        return View(Student);
    }
    // POST: Students/Edit/5
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific you  to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,Nama,Kelas,Brand")] Student Student, Bag Bag)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(Student).State = EntityState.Modified;
            //db.Entry(Bag).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.Id = new SelectList(db.Bag, "Id", "Brand", Student.Bag.Id);
        ViewBag.Id = new SelectList(db.Students, "Id", "Nama", Student.Id);

        return View(Student);
    }
```

with ActionResult Create, I can add ID, Name, and Brand, but I confuse how to edit/update the field..because when I click edit in browser, I can edit ID, Name, Class, but Brand didn't change..

what is method for edit in two table? 
can anyone correct my code?

thank you for your attention :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, when asking about issues like this always post your entity classes, not your table structure. Your table structure is irrelevant as it is not necessarily the same as what's going on in your code.

That said, the issue here is like due to `ModelState`. See, MVC composes an object called `ModelState` with data from a variety of sources: namely `Model`, `Request` and `ViewData`/`ViewBag`. MVC uses the `ModelState` object to render form field values, handle validation, etc. That means that values in `ViewBag` can and will override values from the post body and on the model instance itself.

As a result, anything you put in to `ViewBag` should not be named similarly to anything on your model, or you'll end up with weird behavior. In this instance, because you're setting a select list in `ViewBag.Id`, this select list will be used as the value for your model's `Id` property, which is obviously not correct. Just change the name to something unique like `ViewBag.BagChoices`.

Finally, it's a very bad idea to use your entity class directly to post to, along with using `Bind` to limit properties can be posted. First, `Bind` requires passing property names as strings, which means you now have something you need to maintain. If you add or remove a property or change the name of a property, then suddenly your form will start behaving incorrectly, or you'll open a security hole, unless you remember to change every usage of `Bind` as well. Let me save you the suspense: you *will* forget to do that.

Additionally, posting to an entity directly is often the source of great confusion because even though it looks and feels like an entity instance, it's actually just a regular old class instance on postback. It is not connected in any way to what's going on in Entity Framework, and unless you handle it just right, you'll often end up raising runtime exceptions from trying to interact with other actual entities from Entity Framework. Again, allow me to save you suspense: you will mess that up occasionally.

It's better to use a view model, a class which contains only the properties of your entity you want to be modified. You then map your entity to/from this view model. Not only is this safer, since everything remains strongly-typed, but it forces you to follow best practices such as never writing user-provided data directly to a database. It also allows you to add additional properties that have nothing to do with what needs to be persisted to a database, such as a property to hold your select list. The entity should only be concerned with business rules that apply to persistence. A view model allows you to apply business rules regarding the view, without interfering with or caring about persistence.

Comment: Thank you for your excellent response..

First,  I post the issue, in a rush, and I didn't any screenshot about the model..sorry for that..

based on what you told to me 
"It's better to use a view model, a class which contains only the properties of your entity you want to be modified. .."

can you give me an example or reference about it? because I'm still learning MVC, searching on google, read ebooks about mvc from alliteboo*, but I didn't find example for one to one relationship, I understand about one to many, many to many, how to create CRUD function, etc..

In the end, I thank to you

Answer (score 0):

You have assigned ViewBag.Id twice on your ActionResult Edit for post method.

```
ViewBag.Id = new SelectList(db.Bag, "Id", "Brand", Student.Bag.Id);
ViewBag.Id = new SelectList(db.Students, "Id", "Nama", Student.Id);
```

This might cause an issue when the view is displayed after a failed post.

On your Edit.cshtml for Student,

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.brand, (SelectList)ViewBag.Id)
```

To make sure that the brand is being assigned on your student.

I am assuming that in the Student model there is a property named Brand with type int or whatever the type of your Student.Id is.

Comment: yep, I assigned ViewBag,Id twice, because I curious if it works or not..maybe I re-create new project/solution, start from the beginning..and I will ask a question again very clear, how to make CRUD function / update function in MVC using two tables with one to one relationships..

thank you for your help:)

Answer (score 0):

Transfer data to the page via model. For example you pass **Student**  on the *View*

```
return View(Student);
```

Create a class of model and add Student and add your lists. **ViewBag** not always good. For example:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public Student Student { get; set; }
    public SelectList BagList { get; set; }
    public SelectList StudentsList { get; set; }
}
```

and pass data to the *View*:

```
var model = new MyModel();
model.BagList = new SelectList(db.Bag, "Id", "Brand", Student.Bag.Id);
model.StudentsList = new SelectList(db.Students, "Id", "Nama", Student.Id);
model.Student = Student;    
return View(model);
```

And on your *View* add:

```
@model /*your namespace*/MyModel
```

And change all methods where using *View*. And you have assigned ViewBag.Id twice. Sorry for my English.

Comment: Sorry for late response, I will try this...
hope it works..

thank you for your help and attention..

Comment: @redburn,  your welcome. I try not to use *ViewBag* and transmits the data through Model.